# <body> and onload setTimeout with history.go

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following page that has a button called "update". 
[updatepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR9Qd.png)

If the user click on the update button, i will redirect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5pjp.png)

What i want is, if the user click on the button update, it show the redirect pages for 2-4seconds, and it will back to the "history.go"

Here is I tried so far, I put onload on body (in redirect page form)

```
<body id="main_body" onload="setTimeout(history.go(-2), 4000);">
```

The problem is, the page is not wait for 4 seconds, after I click on the update button, it will instantly redirect to the (history.go(-2)). It should wait 4 seconds (in redirect page form) then after 4 seconds, it will go to history.go(-2). How to overcome this ? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){history.go(-2);}, 4000);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much ! sorry for my mistake, I forgot to use setTimeout function. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

or with the arrow function syntax (shorter)

```
<body id="main_body" onload="setTimeout(()=>{history.go(-2)}, 4000);">
```